# Bitwise operation result and booleans

Tags: c++, c

The code that frustrates me is as follows:

```
bool a = 0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0 == 0x00000FF0;
if (a) {
  Serial.println("True");
} else {
  Serial.println("False");
}
```

This prints "False". I really can't understand why.
Some more tests:

```
bool a = 0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0 == 0x00000FF0;
Serial.println(a);
```

prints `0`.

And:

```
unsigned long a = 0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0;
Serial.println(a, HEX);
```

prints `FF0`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Surely just set a = True?

Comment: Erm... Well that's what puzzled me, it was a part of bigger code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator precedence, compile with warnings:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘&’ [-Wparentheses]
```

Change to

```
bool a = (0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0) == 0x00000FF0;
```

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), this parses as

```
0x00000FF0 & (0x00000FF0 == 0x00000FF0)
```

when you want

```
(0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0) == 0x00000FF0
```

Add the parentheses and you should get the expected result.

Comment: Best answer, very simple and explanative!

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple matter of precedence.

From the sound of things, you'are assuming that: `0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0 == 0x00000FF0;` will be treated as: `(0x00000FF0 & 0x00000FF0) == 0x00000FF0;`, but in fact it's the same as: `0x00000FF0 & (0x00000FF0 == 0x00000FF0);`.

The latter being the case, the result is obviously false--`==` produces either `0` or `1`, and `0xff0 & 1` and `0xff0 & 0` or both 0.